DataLoader CSV Bulk API not loading field values if first processed record does not have all fields populated
Has anyone else ran into issues using DataLoader where if the first row of the CSV file that is loaded successfully does not have values for every possible field in the file, it will fail to load?
For example, take CSV File with header "fieldA","fieldB","fieldC". If the first row of your file has values for fields A and B but not C, and it is loaded successfully, then any subsequent rows in that file will fail to load any value for fieldC, even if the row has it.
Poking around, I found this article https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4SJDSA3 on the topic, which seems to match up with the behavior I am seeing, but beyond filling out all field values for the load, there doesn't seem to be any additional info. Does anyone know why this is happening and if there is a workaround beyond "load it via batch" or "Populate all the values with valid options"?
